# Insert Value into Pandas DataFrame using Column Index

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to insert a value into a pandas data frame using row index and column index? Everything I've seen online uses row index and column NAME. I have a dataframe with a single column of lists, and I want to expand each row's list to single values in multiple columns of a new data frame. Basically I want to be able to iterate through a column of lists, and for every item in the list at `df.iloc[i]`, I want to append it to a new dataframe by using something like:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
   for j in range(len(df.iloc[i])):
       new_df.iloc[i][j] = df.iloc[i][j]
```

It looks like you can only insert values into dataframes by using the column name (not index), which makes an iterative task like this so difficult. Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Comment: "I have a dataframe with a single column of lists, and I want to expand each row's list to single values in multiple columns of a new data frame" - this sounds like an xy problem.

Comment: You can use the name with `loc` and index with `iloc`, which you already seem to be doing, what are you really trying to achieve? Please give an example.

Comment: This demonstrates exactly what I was trying to do: I was originally trying to iterate through a column of lists and map items from the list into other columns. I'm still confused why I can't seem to insert values into a dataframe using a column and row index. But this should show you what I was hoping to do. Thanks for the responses. https://datascienceparichay.com/article/split-pandas-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns/